# Can we detect the user has automate the swipe and click using script in android?

Tags: java, android

i am develop like a game to swipe more and more.
who swipe more i will give him a rank, so i want to prevent the user from automating the script in his favor to get the rank

1.so i want some suggestion and solution if you people have it. i am checking through sensor but how it resolve i can not configure. i have weak English. thanks in advance.

this is what i tried

```
            try {
                x = event.getX(mActivePointerId);
                y = event.getY(mActivePointerId);
                success = true;
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                Log.w(TAG, "Exception in onTouch(view, event) : " + mActivePointerId, e);
            }
            if (success) {
                // Remember where we started
                aDownTouchX = x;
                aDownTouchY = y;
                //to prevent an initial jump of the magnifier, aposX and aPosY must
                //have the values from the magnifier frame
                if (aPosX == 0) {
                    aPosX = frame.getX();
                }
                if (aPosY == 0) {
                    aPosY = frame.getY();
                }

                if (y < objectH / 2) {
                    touchPosition = TOUCH_ABOVE;
                } else {
                    touchPosition = TOUCH_BELOW;
                }
```

Comment: please formatting the question because i dont know..

Comment: I formatted the question for you and removed the 'security' and 'android-security' tags.

If, however, you think this question relates to those tags, feel free to add them back. To me this looks just like a simple gamedev question which has nothing to do with hackers, hacking memory and/or compromising the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an idea, but I'm not sure if it's the right one and it may be not so easy to implement (especially if you are not familiar with RxJava).

I would do it in the following way:

1. Create swipe listener
2. Wrap swipe listener with RxJava Observable
3. Subscribe this Observable
4. Use `throttleLast(...)` operator to filter items emitted every given amount of time (e.g. every 500 milliseconds, 1 second, 3 seconds, anything you want)

In this solution, when someone, will create a bot or script, which will be swiping automatically, application won't count swipes which were made faster than it could be possible to do by a human. Of course, it's not perfect solution, because bot still will score something, but his results would be possible to achieve by human as well.

Comment: thank you so much..you give me some idea but not fully helped.if you have any other idea to move because if it does not fulfill all condition then it's prior to use else what ?

Comment: Your problem is actually an open question, so I'm not sure if it's possible to give you exact and concrete solution. I have one more idea. You can force user to type token during swiping (what isn't convenient) or create your game in such way that user will have to swipe in a different direction every time basing on some graphical or textual information on the screen. It will be much harder to write bot, which will score more points.